# SQL Stored Procedure issue due to the Lack of SP Performance

Tags: performance, time, sql-execution-plan

The main problem is that in my sp there are different objects and logic that may cause lack of performance.

The things that I see on my SP and the tables that are in use in the SP
1- Temp tables such as shown below; (2 Temp Tables)

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE(
  AB INT NOT NULL,
  AC INT NOT NULL,
  AD INT NOT NULL,
  AF INT NULL,
  AG INT NULL,
  REFERENCE_NUMBER INT NULL
 )
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 ON #TEMP_TABLE (AB , AC, AD)

2- Insert process to the create temp table as TEMP1 in the SP

3- DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
   DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE2
in the end of the SP

4- There are two tables used to join themselves, but not all the fields that are used "on" case of JOIN operator. For instance; there are clustered index fields declared on the first table, plus date column which is not in the clustered index groups of the first table..

For short; Clustered and non clustered indexes are important ok, but in which order should i declare them. What i need from which index type, tell me the order of cretation of indexes for further use of JOIN process etc.

5- Should I use table variable instead of temp table.  Ok it will be better but there are lots of question mark that does not let me to use the table variables..

*An INSERT into a table variable will not take advantage of parallelism. 
[ref->](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html)

6- I heard about logical reads. Should i really take care about these numbers.
The details of an example data's results are shown below (*)

7- The execution plan...

[image: Execution Plan]

*OUTPUT:

> Table 'CHANNEL'. Scan count 0, logical
>   reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
>   0. Table 'XYZ_DATE'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'XYZ01'. Scan count 3171,
>   logical reads 13135, physical reads
>   153, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical
>   reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'XYZ02'. Scan count
>   5, logical reads 51256, physical reads
>   0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical
>   reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   '#TEMP_TABLE_________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000840'. Scan count 0, logical reads 97,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical
>   reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
>   0.
>
> (32 row(s) affected) Table
>   '#TEMP_TABLE2________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000841'. Scan count 0, logical reads 64,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   ''XYZ03'. Scan count 0,
>   logical reads 107, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table ''XYZ04''.
>   Scan count 32, logical reads 129,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   '#TEMP_TABLE_________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000840'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (21 row(s) affected)
>
> (21 row(s) affected) Table
>   'XYZ05'. Scan count 0,
>   logical reads 87, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'XYZ01A'. Scan count 21, logical
>   reads 147, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table 'XYZ04'.
>   Scan count 0, logical reads 84,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   '#TEMP_TABLE2________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000841'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(*)

Comment: Rebuild the indexes on the concerned tables and then run the query again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did put some indexes then scans are doing seek..
now it is better.

still doing performance tests:
follow here-> [Testing Stored Procedure performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324699/testing-stored-procedure-performance)