# Testing Stored Procedure performance

Tags: asp.net, web-services, performance

I did some operations on my tables to get faster SP operations against to time-out problem on a web service method which uses that problematic SP.

I was trying to compare SP perfomance but i could not get on well on that sie. See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311189/comparing-stored-procedure-performance-ex-and-new-version) please.

Clearly, **I want to see if I get time-out problem after all SP modifications on development scope.** If everything goes well, I will put my new indexes to  PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT, the indexes which helps the SP to run faster against to time-out problem.

1- How can I be sure Web.Config file does let the SP run itself until the operation will be completed successfully.
this configuration eneough ?

```
<configuration>

<location path="~/WebService.asmx">

<system.web>

<httpRuntime timeout="700"/>

</system.web>

</location>

</configuration>
```

OR,
Should i edit the connection string for time-out duration?

```
Connect Timeout=30
```

Regards
BK

**References:**

[Comparing SP performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311189/comparing-stored-procedure-performance-ex-and-new-version)

**Edit:**

> Nina : Sql fora profiler result
>   How shold I consider the results of the Profiler..?
>   [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8a7925c767.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8a7925c767.jpg)

Comment: @Attention! OLD and NEW vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at testing your stored procedure performance you should use the profiling tools of the RDBMS (E.G., the query execution plan, profiler, etc) instead of using the a web service.

Comment: @Nina have you checked the "Edit" section ?